# A sum that's possibly equal to the Euler-Mascheroni Constant $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n!}{n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, gamma-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

The following interesting sum seems to approach the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n!}{n^3} \overset{?}{=} \gamma$$

I've looked at the different ways to express the Euler-Mascheroni constant and tried to apply those methodes to this sum.

I also tried using the series representation of $\displaystyle \frac{\ln n!}{n^3}$ for $\displaystyle n=0,1,2$

and using the log gamma function

$$\displaystyle\ln \Gamma(n+1)=-\gamma-\gamma n-\ln (n+1)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{n+1}{k}\right)$$

This problem might be quite well out of my mathmatical reach but I still would love to know the answer. It would be awesome if anyone could prove or disprove that the sum equals the Euler-Mascheroni constant and show their method.

Comment: The first 10,000 terms sum to $0.583\ldots$ which is above $\gamma$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(n!)/n^3≈0.557685$, $\gamma\approx 0.57721566490$

Comment: @Snaw with what did you calculate that?

Comment: @Yanick I used WolframAlpha, I hope it is indeed accurate. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1..10000+ln%28n%21%29%2Fn%5E3

Comment: I ran this on python to make sure: sum(log(factorial(n))/n**3 for n in range(1,2000)) and it gives a number above $0.58$.

Comment: @Yanick How did you stumble across this?

Comment: @Snaw I was just playing around with the different ways to express $\gamma$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.ii) that for $n\geq 1$,
$$
\log n! > \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \frac{1}{{12n}} - \frac{1}{{360n^3 }}.
$$
Thus
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\log n!}}{{n^3 }}} & > \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^2 }}}  + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^3 }}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \\ &\quad + \log \sqrt {2\pi } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}}  + \frac{1}{{12}}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^4 }}}  - \frac{1}{{360}}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^6 }}} 
\\ & =  - \zeta '(2) - \frac{1}{2}\zeta '(3) - \zeta (2) + \zeta (3)\log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \frac{1}{{12}}\zeta (4) - \frac{1}{{360}}\zeta (6) \\ & = 0.583661 \ldots>\gamma. 
\end{align*}
For the values of the derivative of $\zeta$ I used the OEIS [A073002](https://oeis.org/A073002) and [A244115](https://oeis.org/A244115). The other values can be expressed in terms of $\pi$.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is a little bit above $\gamma$ or is that a coincidence?

Comment: @Snaw Most likely coincidence. Being within about 1% of it isn't that surprising when you consider how many numbers there are to go around. It's unlikely that this is a $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ style situation.

Comment: Pure coincidence, nothing special here.

Comment: @Gary Thank for the awesome answer! I don't really get where $\log n! > \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + \log \sqrt {2\pi }  + \frac{1}{{12n}} - \frac{1}{{360n^3 }}$ for $n\geq 1$ comes from.

Comment: @Yanick $\log n! = \log \Gamma (n + 1) = \log \Gamma (n) + \log n$. Now apply the first sentence of the paragraph I linked by truncating 5.11.1 after the first term. The error is between $0$ and $-\frac{1}{360n^3}$. But this has been proved a thousand times before in many other places. See, for instance, Corollary 3 [here](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/284957/file/451038.pdf).